# Wait for OpenCL kernel termination, but only during some time

Tags: opencl

To wait for kernel termination on the host side I can do this:

```
error = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(..., &event);
CHECK_ERROR(error);
clWaitForEvents(1, &event);
```

But is there a way to precise some maximal time of waiting? That is, if my kernel is not finished after, let's say, 10 seconds I'd like to continue, but if it takes only one second of execution I don't want to wait for the 9 remaining seconds.

Comment: BTW, if your kernel takes more than a few second the OS might terminate it (since the GPU is also needed to draw your desktop). You should design your kernels to execute is less than a second, ideally less than 10 ms.

Comment: @Dithermaster yes of course, it was just an example, not very carefully chosen tho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to wait only for a given amount of time, however you can:

- Check if the event has finished every N seconds via `clGetEventInfo()` and a loop.
- Use `clSetEventCallback()` to define a function that will be called when the event completes. Sleep the current thread for 10 seconds, and make the event callback wake the thread if it finishes quicker than 10 seconds.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I don't like first solution at all, second one is a bit complicated for such simple task, but if there is no other way, I will stick with that one, thanks once again.

Comment: Is clGetEventInfo always safe for host-side? Can I trust clGetEventInfo 100% if all I need is to start using data that arrives from an enqueueRead/Write? https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clGetEventInfo.html says "Using clGetEventInfo to determine if a command identified by event has finished execution (i.e. CL_EVENT_COMMAND_EXECUTION_STATUS returns CL_COMPLETE) is not a synchronization point". Not a synchronization point for device? Or host?